# Segmentation fault from std::_Rb_tree_increment (__x=0x1)

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I get a segmentation fault when iterating over a set.

The stack trace points to:

```
  0x000000081193ccc5 in std::_Rb_tree_increment (__x=0x1) at /libstdc++/src/tree.cc:68
  0x0000000806c3107e in std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<test *>::operator++     at stl_tree.h:266
```

but I get nothing more informative but the last line of crash is as below.

The iterator is over a set.

```
 typedef std::set<test*,test_less> test_set_t;

 test_set_t& set(bt->getSet());   // getSet() will return reference to the class bt member variable set

 test_set_t::iterator pos = set.begin();

 test empty(val);
 test* last_ptr = &empty;

 for (; pos != set.end(); last_ptr = *pos++) {       // gdb shows this as last line
```

I cannot see the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what's in the body of the loop, since the fault might be caused by something in there (but only gets recognized by the line you mention).

Comment: A complete minimal testcase would be useful to hunt down this bug as it looks like you are invoking UB somewhere, and since symptoms of UB can appear everywhere, not in the line that is causing it, presenting real code is the only sane way to debug stuff in a structured way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely either the set is empty or you erased the item `pos` was pointing to while iterating.

Comment: As this crash which I am getting is not reproducible and the inside code is complex to discuss it here(as calling functions). Can someone suggest to get the same core with the help of sample program for set. It will be very helpful for me to debug that way.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the similar problem

```
set<int> sec;
sec.insert(1);
set<int>::iterator iter = sec.begin();
iter = sec.erase(iter);
cout << 1 << endl;
iter = sec.erase(iter);
cout << 1 << endl;
```

_Rb_tree_increment may be locked if the iterator passed to it is invalid or corrupted, such as the end iterator of an empty set.
So we can insert Sentinel node to guarantee set will not null or check set is null.